# How to allow only digits?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help fix the script.

html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phone" id="phoneInput" ng-change="apt.changePhoneInput(phone)">
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Appctrl', Appctrl, '$scope');
function Appctrl($scope){
  this.changePhoneInput = function(phone) {
    var result = phone;
    console.log('phone', phone);
    result.replace(/[^+0-9\(\)]/gim,'');
    console.log('result', result);
    $scope.phone = result;
  };
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z9kxuvps/28/)

I want to allow to enter only numbers and follow symbols: '+', '(', ')', '-'. But after enter any symbols replace does not work

Comment: using HTML5?  `input type="number" ... >`

Comment: Need to escape `+` and `-`. You can use `\d` instead of `0-9`.

Comment: come to think of it you can alternatively use `< input type='text' pattern='<regex pattern>' ... >`

Comment: or, based on your JS, this: `<input type='tel' ...>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing Assignment to `result` variable, After replacing the characters excepts number

```
result=result.replace(/[^+0-9\(\)-]/gim,'');
```

After Change you are controller should be like

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Appctrl', Appctrl, '$scope');
function Appctrl($scope){
  this.changePhoneInput = function(phone) {
    var result = phone;
    console.log('phone', phone);
    result=result.replace(/[^+0-9\(\)-]/gim,'');
    console.log('result', result);
    $scope.phone = result;
  };
}
```